# Ruby: if condition in attributes to handle missing key-value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I have a resource class that I use as intermediate DTO for mapping from my model to my API response. I would like to prevent any situation in which any part of the response payload might be delivered as nil. This is what I have

```
attr_reader :json_block, :element  

def initialize(attributes = {})
 @json_block = attributes['some_json']
 @element = attributes['some_json']['element']
 ....
```

I thought I could have an something along these lines:

```
if attributes['json_block'].exists?
  @json_block = attributes['json_block']
  @element = attributes['element']
end
```

Is this the correct approach? I would like a solution whereby if it comes in nil, we can ignore it and unmarshall the payload.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean `attributes.key?('json_block')`? Possibly also `@element = attributes.dig('some_json','element')`.

Comment: I am confused is `'element'` nested like in Example 1 or flat like in example 2. For Example 2: `@json_block, @element = attributes.values_at('json_block','element')` will result in the exact same outcome as the conditional you have right now. For Example 1: `@json_block = attributes['some_json']; @element = @json_block&.[]('element')` would work.

Comment: What about converting this JSON object into a hash and use `.compact` method which will remove all empty key/value pairs? Can you provide an example JSON obj?

Comment: Thank you all, do you have an exmpl for this @OliverKristen

Comment: Yes. So you can parse a JSON into a hash like the following exmaple:

`require 'json'`
`value = '{"val":"","val1":"test1","val2":"nil"}'`
`hash = JSON.parse(value) # => {"val"=>"","val1"=>"test1","val2"=>"nil}`

Afterwards you can use the method `.compact` on that hash, like this:
`puts hash.compact # => { "val1" => "test1" }`

And in case you need a JSON back you could to `hash.compact.to_json`

Comment: To clairfy, the JSON I am dealing with looks like this:

`json_block: { element: true, another_element: false....}`

Comment: I have no knowledge of the values for each element at this stage, so not quite sure how this can be done. My resource is acting as a DTO to map the response I am getting from an API